# Why is super().__init__(*args,**kwargs) being used when class doesn't specify a superclass?

Tags: python

I understand why super() is used when a class is a subclass of a superclass, but what is the superclass of a class that doesn't specify the superclass in the subclass parameters? Here's my code:

```
import random


class Sneaky:
    sneaky = True

    def __init__(self, sneaky=True, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.sneaky = sneaky

    def hide(self, light_level):
        return self.sneaky and light_level < 10


class Agile:
    agile = True

    def __init__(self, agile=True, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.agile = agile

    def evade(self):
        return self.agile and random.randint(0, 1)
```

Comment: It is `object`. You include `super` so that everything continues to work when you introduce multiple inheritance.

Comment: because you will not miss add that once you add inheritance one day. you are right in this case it does nothing

Comment: So you mean that it allows things to continue to work if, for example:         class Thief(Agile,Sneaky): body...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Suppose `Sneaky` is used as part of a multiple inheritance class structure such as:

```
class Sneaky:
    sneaky = True

    def __init__(self, sneaky=True, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.sneaky = sneaky

    def hide(self, light_level):
        return self.sneaky and light_level < 10

class Person:
    def __init__(self, human=True, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.human = human

class Thief(Sneaky, Person): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


t = Thief()
print(t.human)
# True
```

Since

```
In [62]: Thief.mro()
Out[62]: [__main__.Thief, __main__.Sneaky, __main__.Person, object]
```

- `Thief.__init__`'s  `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` calls `Sneaky.__init__`.
- `Sneaky.__init__`'s `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` calls `Person.__init__`.

If the `super().__init__` call were removed from `Sneaky.__init__`, then `t.human` would raise

```
AttributeError: 'Thief' object has no attribute 'human'
```

because `Person.__init__` would not get called.

Comment: Thank you for this! So basically, it's used to avoid problems down the road if you decided to create a superclass whose subclasses were those with the super().__init__() methods?

Comment: Yes that's one case. Someone else might use your class in an unanticipated way too. So if you want to make the class compatible with multiple inheritance, *every* class's `__init__` must call `super().__init__`.